# Using Bootstrap Dropdown on a centered image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the Bootstrap dropdown on a centered image, but I can't get the dropdown to be centered as well.

[Fiddle with my current code](http://jsfiddle.net/WgGCs/3/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 profile-picture text-center">
        <div class="dropdown col-md-3">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9qfJGrz.jpg" alt="" class="profile-photo img-thumbnail" data-toggle="dropdown" />
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="Change Settings">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Upload new picture</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the dropdown gets aligned to the left, is there a way to get it to be centered underneath the image? It's in a `col-md-3` so try resizing the screen as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add display:inline-block to your dropdown.

```
.dropdown
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/WgGCs/5/)

Comment: like this! 1 more fix: change dropdown's width to 170px

Comment: @DanielCheung Yeah I agree. It would look better if the width of the dropdown menu was the same as the image. Since Adam's dropdown menu was already smaller than 170px I'll let him decide. (but I agree with you that it's better) :)

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution than mine (it's easy to overlook something like this when you can't see the bootstrap styling!), +1 for this.

Comment: Such a clean 1-line code! I'm very surprised! Keep up good work :D

Answer (score 1):

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WgGCs/4/)

This would be one solution, which will work responsively as long as you declare a width for the menu:

```
.profile-photo {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin-left: -85px;
  width: 170px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;    
}
```

I removed your `col-md-3` as you are just positioning the menu halfway across the `col-md-12` with this method.

Comment: The only problem with that is any content below it gets pushed down, rather than be under the dropdown: http://jsfiddle.net/Df9Ug/

Comment: No problem, just use `position: absolute;` see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Df9Ug/1/ @Adam

Answer (score 1):

`position: absolute`, `left:0px` and `float:left` are the causes.

Fix:

```
.profile-picture .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
```

The width will stick the the width of the column :)

If you don't like that, use these, or **remove the column setup**:

```
width: 170px;
margin: 0 auto;
```